# Bar chart offset and layer overlays

Tags: r, ggplot2, shift, geom-bar

Hello all R enthusiasts

I have a problem with doing a bar graph that should look like this:

I do not have 10 reputation points so I have to use a link (four bars in one category) http://matma4u.pl/uploads/imgs/pre_1499074482__wyk2.jpg

Generally I would like the same effect

I tried to put four series of charts and post bars but unfortunately did not work out.

I am also convinced that there is a better way

For speeding up my work I send data

```
dane <- data.frame(kraj=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L),
            rok=c(rep(2010,6),rep(2014,6)),
                Kat1=c(c(1627,1144,1100,1085,983,639),c(1827,1444,1400,1285,1183,1039)),
            Kat2=c(c(1500,1244,1168,1110,1002,863), c(1400,1144,1568,1510,999,800))
)
dane

dane$kraj <- factor(d$kraj, levels=1:6, labels=c("Polska", "Niemcy", "Austria", "Rosja", "Ukraina", "Francja"))

dane$rok <- factor(d$rok,levels=c(2010,2014))
```

---

```
    ggplot(dane,aes(x = kraj, y = Kat1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "darkgreen") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Kat1,label = format(Kat1, big.mark = " ")), vjust = -0.5, hjust = 0.5, cex = 3)+
  geom_bar(aes(y = Kat2), width = 0.5, stat = "identity", fill = "green")+
  geom_text(aes(y = Kat2,label = format(Kat2, big.mark = " ")),colour = "red", vjust = -0.5, hjust = 0.5, cex = 3)
```

My code joins series (kat1, kat2) from two years, no labels are visible, I do not know how to move the bars

I know the values in the image are different, they are examples

Please help with the code design of such a chart

Comment: What errors are you receiving @Jarekzulus for people to help :)

Comment: I don't understand a word of what's going on that site, and I don't see any plot either. Pls make you question self-explanatory.

Comment: Sorry, I do not speak English well

Comment: I can not apply graph layers to look like the attached link.

I would add a picture but I can not - not enough points :)

Comment: I added my unfortunately incorrect code

Comment: We still don't know what your expected output is. The site you linked requires registration, no plot is visible.

Comment: My mistake
Link to graphics from another site

http://matma4u.pl/uploads/imgs/pre_1499074482__wyk2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Such an effect I would like to get. How to put these graphs on yourself

http://matma4u.pl/uploads/imgs/pre_1499074482__wyk2.jpg

The data is presented above